# Python - selenium - google map not visible in page_source

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape GPS coordinates data off a property listing

```
https://www.primelocation.com/new-homes/details/55357965?search_identifier=d10d089a335cc707245fb6c924bafbd2
```

The coordinates are located on the "Map & Nearby" tab in the following HTML block of code:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=51.517204,-0.126447&amp;z=15&amp;t=m&amp;hl=en-GB&amp;gl=US&amp;mapclient=apiv3" title="Open this area in Google Maps (opens a new window)" style="position: static; overflow: visible; float: none; display: inline;"><div style="width: 66px; height: 26px; cursor: pointer;"><img alt="" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/google_white5_hdpi.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 66px; height: 26px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div></a>
```

Specfically: `https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=51.517204,-0.126447&z=15&t=m&hl=en-GB&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3`

The intended output is to extract the coordinates, and have them printed out, i.e.

```
Latitude: 51.517204
Longitude: -0.126447
```

With the help of fellow SO users, I have managed to get to "Map & Nearby" tab, where I was hoping I could then just go to appropriate HTML block, and regex the coordinates.

The code so far is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

PATH = r"C:\Users\...\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities())

url = 'https://www.primelocation.com/new-homes/details/55357965?search_identifier=d10d089a335cc707245fb6c924bafbd2'
driver.get(url)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Map & nearby')]")))
element.click()
```

The chrome window that pops up displays the website correctly, however when I run `print(driver.page_source)` to check how Python sees it, google map is missing, hence I am not able to extract the coordinates.
Output from `page_source` is here: https://codeshare.io/5wgRvB

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(
    "https://www.primelocation.com/new-homes/details/55357965?search_identifier=d10d089a335cc707245fb6c924bafbd2")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Map & nearby']")))
element.click()
time.sleep(5)
Map_Url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=')]")
myurl = str(Map_Url.get_attribute('href'))


def find_between(s, first, last):
    try:
        start = s.index(first) + len(first)
        end = s.index(last, start)
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""


Info = find_between(myurl, "https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=", "&z=15&t=m&hl=en-US&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3")
lat_long = Info.split(',')
print("Latitiue :-", lat_long[0])
print("Longitude :-", lat_long[1])
```

Note - If this is what you are looking for then please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Lat & Long value you can use the regular expression as well.
You need to `import re` and use the following **regex** expression.

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.primelocation.com/new-homes/details/55357965?search_identifier=d10d089a335cc707245fb6c924bafbd2")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Map & nearby']"))).click()
nearesturl=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[href^='https://maps.google.com/maps?ll']"))).get_attribute('href')
match=re.findall("\d+\.\d+",nearesturl)
print(match[0])
print("-" + match[1])
```